# How to populate a field on Contact from Related Task

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks

I have a field on Task `Test_Time__c` (Date/Time). How can I fetch this field and populate on `Last_Login_Time__c` on Related Contact record?

Below is task on Contact

[image: Task on Contact]

Below is the related Contact

[image]

Tried to add this trigger on Task

```
trigger lastLogin on Task (after insert, after update, before insert, before update) { 

Map<Id, List<Task>> taskWhatIds = new Map<Id, List<Task>>{};

    for (Task t : trigger.new) {
        if (t.WhatId != null) {
        List<Task> tasks = taskWhatIds.get(t.WhatId);
        if (tasks == null) {
            tasks = new List<Task>();
            taskWhatIds.put(t.WhatId, tasks);
        }
        tasks.add(t); 
    }
}

for (Contact c: [Select Id, Last_login_time__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :taskWhatIds.keySet()]){
    for (task t : taskWhatIds.get(c.id)){
        t.test_time__c = c.last_login_time__c;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Deleting your old question and creating a nearly identical one is borderline abusive behavior, especially when both are already near duplicates of a question you asked yesterday. In the future, just edit. Regardless of all that, have you made any attempt to write this trigger yourself? Are you stuck somewhere specifically?

Comment: Sorry! Got it! can I continue with this post or shall I undelete the previous post and delete this one?

Comment: At this point you will have a deleted post either way. Just stick with what you've got and **[edit]** with any clarifications.

Comment: Yes I tried a trigger on Task, I had added it to the question. No errors on Trigger, but it wouldn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger doesn't do anything to the `Contact` at all.

```
for (Contact c: [Select Id, Last_login_time__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :taskWhatIds.keySet()]){
    for (task t : taskWhatIds.get(c.id)){
        t.test_time__c = c.last_login_time__c;
    }
}
```

You need to make two specific changes here:

1. You're assigning to a field on `t`, the Task, rather than `c`, the Contact. You need to fix this by modifying the Contact.
2. You also do not perform DML. From a `Task` trigger, you must fire an `update` DML to persist your changes to a Contact. You need to build a `List` of contacts to update and do `update contactList` at the end of your trigger.

I'm pretty sure you don't need this running `after insert, after update, before insert, before update`. `after insert` should be enough.

Comment: Where should I modify my code? 
I changed c.Last_Login_Time__c = t.Test_Time__c; ... also just added after Insert.

Comment: I'm happy to expand on my answer if it's not clear, but I'm not able to write the code for you.

Comment: Anything that helps @David, I have been trying to resolve this from three days in multiple ways. I tried Process Builder, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211193/unable-to-get-last-login-date-time-of-user-on-contact-object, none of them works, let me know if you have a better solution, thanks much.

Comment: What aspects are you not clear on? I would be happy to provide links to resources that may help. This is not complex Apex, but I understand that as a new developer the scope can be overwhelming.

Comment: In our org we convert Contact into Portal User.. my requirement was to populate the “LoginTime” from User Record onto related contact record(custom field Last Login Time)...  I started on writing a trigger on Contact object then User object then I switched to Process Builder.. and now writing a trigger on Task.. let me know if this is clear..

Comment: I have tried to clarify my answer. I would also strongly recommend completing the Trailhead modules on Apex and triggers, and reading through the Apex Developer Guide. Doing so will build the conceptual vocabulary that will help you ask good questions and give you the ability to effectively integrate suggestions into your code.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed I was able to fix my issue with those articles, thanks much!